# Getting value from AttributeBag

Tags: php, symfony

I don't know how correctly get value form AttributeBag. Symfony documentation is not clear for me with this issue.
Some code:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $session = new Session();
    $mybag=new AttributeBag('user');
    $mybag->set('first','michel');
    $mybag->set('last','voler');
    $session->registerBag($mybag);
    $w=$mybag->get('user/first');     
    return new Response($w);
}
```

Thank for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `NamespacedAttributeBag`: provides structured storage of session attributes using a name spacing character in the key. As example:

```
    $mybag=new NamespacedAttributeBag();
    $mybag->set('user/first','michel');
    $mybag->set('user/last','voler');
    $session->registerBag($mybag);
    $w=$mybag->get('user/first');
    return new Response($w);
```

More [info](http://www.andreagiuliano.it/make-your-session-namespaced/) in this article.

Hope this help

**PS: The value specified in the constructor identified The key used to store attributes in the session**

Comment: Thanks Matteo for suggestion